# Hibernate mapping with partitioned MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, partitioning

I have a MySQL database where (most) tables are partitioned on a column TENANT_ID.  Each table also has an ID field which uses AUTO_INCREMENT and is therefore unique across all partitions.  The database primary key is a combination (ID, TENANT_ID) due to MySQL's requirement to have the partition column part of the primary key.

In my Java code I have mapped only the ID column with the @Id annotation.  This was mostly to avoid the many problems around composite keys in Hibernate.  The problem I am facing now is that most SQL statements generated by Hibernate only use the ID column.  For example, an UPDATE statement generated by Hibernate would read as

```
UPDATE object SET value = ? WHERE ID = ?
```

However, since this query excludes any predicate on TENANT_ID, it does not take full advantage of the partitioning and will need to scan every partition until it finds the ID.  I would like for the generated query to yield:

```
UPDATE object SET value = ? WHERE ID = ? AND TENANT_ID = ?
```

My question is whether or not there is an easy way to do this without having to resort to composite keys in JPA as I know many people discourage their use.

Comment: Do you really need these two columns (`TENANT_ID` and `ID`)? Couldn't you just drop the `ID` column altogether, and define `TENANT_ID` as the primary key?

Comment: Option 2: what about partitioning by `ID` instead of `TENANT_ID`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an embedded entity, for instance ObjectPK that encompasses the id and EntityId. than use @EmbeddedId to reference it from the Object entity.